# Scheme Fibonacci series list print

Tags: recursion, scheme, fibonacci

I'm trying to write a recursive function that prints to the screen a list (each number in a new line) of elements of the Fibonacci series for the given parameter n. I need to use the display function to print those numbers and use a helper method as well.

Example:

> (fibo 5)
>   1
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   5

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!!

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, indicating the specific points where you're having problems. Also, try looking for [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme+fibonacci) dealing with the same topic.

Comment: (define fibo (lambda (n)
                    (cond ((eq? n 0) 0)
                          ((eq? n 1) 1)
                          (else (+ (fibo(- n 1)) (fibo(- n 2)))))))

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call your procedure inside a looping function, taking care of printing the elements in the right order and breaking with new lines. Notice that the point where we call the recursion is very important to obtain the desired behavior! (to see this, move the recursive call *after* the line break - the printing order will change).

```
(define print-fibo
  (lambda (n)
    (cond ((> n 0)              ; keep iterating if we haven't reached zero
           (print-fibo (- n 1)) ; advance the recursion
           (display (fibo n))   ; display current value of fibo
           (newline)))))        ; print a new line
```

For example:

```
(print-fibo 5)
1
1
2
3
5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you give a short explanation of this code please?